# How to elegantly model a boolean value and an integer into one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

In JavaScript, I have an object that needs to be processed, and I need to store on the object whether it's currently being processed by some worker. In addition, since processing supports timeouts, in case it currently is processed, I need to store the timeout on the object.

So I have:

- Either the object is not processed,
- or the object is processed, and then the timeout is relevant.

Now I wonder how to model this in an elegant way. The simplest thing you can come up with (and which is also the most explicit one), is to have two properties:

```
isProcessing: false,
isProcessingUntil: 0
```

There you can already see this approach's drawback: In case the object is not being processed, the `isProcessingUntil` property isn't actually needed, and hence the question arises what a reasonable value now is (maybe `undefined`?).

Of course, one could merge both into one, and use the effect that any non-zero number is truthy, so we could also say:

```
isProcessingUntil: 0
```

The fact whether it's currently being processed could then simply be checked by something such as:

```
const isProcessing = !Boolean(isProcessingUntil);
```

Again, this works, but doesn't feel elegant. So, in the end, I would like to avoid casting (like in the second approach), but I would also like to avoid fields that don't make sense under some circumstances.

Besides these two options, is there another reasonable approach to this problem?

Comment: `isProcessingUntil: 0` is falsy. So `isProcessingUntil: anything not 0` is truthy

Comment: What possible values `isProcessingUntil` can hold ?

Comment: Fixed, added an `!`, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @CodeManiac A JavaScript timestamp, i.e. a value such as returned by e.g. `Date.now()`.

Comment: What about `!!isProcessingUntil`? It's the same as `Boolean(isProcessingUntil)` but doesn't it feel more elegant?

Comment: My problem is not the syntax of `Boolean(…)`, it's more that I have the feeling that things aren't conceptually nice here.

Comment: @GoloRoden how about using `+(val && val instanceof Date)` or simply use `+(val)`

Comment: In my opinion, it's fine if you have an optional attribute that is not needed all the time. It's more elegant than casting and your code will know precisely when to make use of what attribute. You can maybe rename the second one to `processingTimeout` or something similar to convey that it's only relevant when something is processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isProcessingUntil` property and declare `isProcessing` as a function property, since you know it depends on `isProcessingUntil`.

```js
let process = {
  isProcessingUntil: 0,
  get isProcessing() { return !!this.isProcessingUntil }
}

console.log(process.isProcessing);
process.isProcessingUntil = 1024;
console.log(process.isProcessing);
```

Comment: I think this is the most viable approach, since it turns `since you know it depends on isProcessingUntil` explicit.

Comment: I'd go with a getter: `let process = { isProcessingUntil: 0, get isProcessing(){ return !!this.isProcessingUntil} }` and `console.log(process.isProcessing);`

Answer (score 0):

Use an integer:

- `-1` if the object is not processed
- `<timeout value>` if the object is being processed

This `-1`-or-integer approach is usual, as seen in `Array.indexOf` (-1 = not found, else: index in array)

Comment: This basically means using a magic value, which (unfortunately) I wouldn't call "elegant".

Comment: The number in this case is a magic value, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)